# Como ingresar datos a un array en bash linux

Tags: linux, bash, script

Estoy tratando de hacer un script en bash linux que me permita ingresar productos, la cantidad de ellos y su precio. Al momento de imprimir los datos este me sale en vertical y no me sale en horizontal tratando que se vea como un recibo.
Lo que no logro hacer es que los datos de las variables me salgan en horizontal y no en vertical.
Agradeceria mucho de su apoyo y si hay alguna otra forma de hacer este script es bienvenida.

```
#! /bin/bash
clear
declare -a colors
echo "Bienvenido al Despacho de Productos"
read -p "Ingresa tu nombre: " nombreUsuario
echo "Bienvenido $nombreUsuario"
echo "Ingrese el nombre del producto"
read -a producto
echo "Ingrese la cantidad del producto"
read -a cantidad
echo "Ingrese el precio de los productos"
read -a precio
echo
element_count = ${#producto[@]}
index = 0 
while [[ "$index" -lt "$element_count" ]]
do
     echo ${producto[$index]}
     echo ${cantidad[$index]}
     echo ${precio[$index]}
     let "index = $index + 1"
done
```

[image: script1]

Comment: iría bien que mostraras gráficamente cómo quieres que se vea el resultado, no acaba de quedar demasiado claro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como tu pregunta es "¿Como ingresar datos a un array en bash linux?" voy a abordar la temática desde esa perspectiva.

Ingresar datos aun array es de la forma `array[indice]=valor`.

Tengo un gusto particular por hacer que mi código se exprese por mi. Así que lo que propongo es una solución donde se preguntan los datos para llenar un array usando las mismas claves del array.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare nombre_de_usuario
declare -A caracteristicas
caracteristicas=(
    [producto]=""
    [cantidad]=""
    [precio]=""
    )

read -p "Ingrese su nombre: " nombre_de_usuario
echo "Hola $nombre_de_usuario"

for caracteristica in ${!caracteristicas[@]}
do
    read -p "Ingrese $caracteristica: "  valor
    caracteristicas[$caracteristica]=$valor
done

caracteristicas[total]=$(bc <<< "${caracteristicas[precio]}*${caracteristicas[cantidad]}")

echo
echo -e "${!caracteristicas[@]}\n${caracteristicas[@]}" | column -t
```

Resultando en algo así:

```
$ ./preguntas.sh
Ingrese su nombre: Marco
Hola Marco
Ingrese precio: 12.21
Ingrese cantidad: 4
Ingrese producto: Sopa

precio  cantidad  producto  total
12.21   4         Sopa      48.84
```

Donde el problema de formato se puede arreglar con un *brace expansion* al usar

```
echo ${caracteristicas[@]}  # Para los valores
echo ${!caracteristicas[@]}  # Para las claves
```

y el parámetro `-e` de `echo` que habilita la interpretación de los caracteres con *backslash* (`\`)

Comment: Muchas gracias hermano, funciono tal cual lo tenia en mente pero no sabia como plasmarlo.

Answer (score 2):

en este caso no es un problema de insertar en arrays, sino de presentacion. Estas utilizando `echo`, que por defecto introduce un salto de linea al final.

Para evitar este tema, puedes utilizar el parametro -e, que te permite interpretar las variables y otros caracteres que introduzcas entre "":

```
echo -e "$producto\t\t$cantidad\t\t$precio\t\t$total\n"
```

En este ejemplo, te va a mostrar el nombre del producto, luego interpreta dos tabulaciones (\t), despues muestra la cantidad, otros dos tabulados, precio... y asi hasta el total. Ademas, he añadido un \n para que te haga el salto de linea.

Tambien puedes utilizar `-n`, que ignora el salto de linea final.

más informacion:  `man echo`

Comment: incluso es mejor usar `printf`, que no asume ningún carácter de más por defecto.